# Unable to create a dataset using OpenAI module

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have been trying to use Dataset attribute in the openAI module to create a dataset that can be used to uplaod at OpenAI and used for finetuning. But it is continuously showing th error- AttributeError: module 'openai' has no attribute 'Dataset'. I havetried to update openAI to the latest version which coming as 0.27.6 and I don't know how to update it to the latest version.

[image]
[image]

Kinldy help me out in how to make it work as I am new to working with openAI APIs.